# Retrieve HTTP Status Code from error() Event in JQuery image.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load an image by Javascript, but know the difference between a 404 and 500 error if it fails.

I have code to load an image into an 'img' tag like the below:

```
var img = $('<img />').attr('src', url)
    .load(function() {
        // Do something.
    })
    .error(function(ev) {
        // What sort of error?
    });
```

In the error() function, I don't seem able to tell whether the error was a 500 or a 404. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I'm surprised that `.error` works at all!  It shouldn't.  Why does jQuery care that you setting the `src` attribute vs. any other attribute?  How/why would it even be able to hook into the HTTP request for an element on the page?

Comment: It's documented functionality: http://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: Interesting!  I had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Handle and test [http status page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) like this

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/38/)**</kbd>

```
var img = $('<img />')
    .load(function() {
        // Do something.
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {  
       if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==404)
       {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
       }
       else
       {
           alert("Something went wrong");
       }
    })
    .attr('src', url);
```

Comment: In Chrome, jqXHR.status seems always to be null. Therefore I seem always to get the 'Something went wrong' alert.

Comment: I don't experiment your problem. Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/38/

Comment: Hmm...how odd. The fiddle doesn’t work for me on Chrome on Mac OS X. Whatever I change the URL to, it shows 'Something went wrong'.

Comment: jQuery only passes an event object to the `error` handler. See [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/error/)