# Get error type when img tag fails to load image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to get the specific error when img tag failed to load an image? Example: Differentiate an "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" error from "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601125/retrieve-http-status-code-from-error-event-in-jquery-image

Comment: The way suggested by that related post does not work :/